# RegEx: How to capture one line before regex match with <delimiter>

Tags: php, regex

I heave this text:

```
II - title - XXXXXXXX
CNPJ: XXXXXXXXXX
test1: XXXXXXXXXX
Test1: XXXXXXXXXX

IIX - XXXXXXXX
CNPJ: XXXXXXXXXX
test2: XXXXXXXXXX
Test2: XXXXXXXXXX
```

I need this:

```
array(
0 => '
    II - title - XXXXXXXX
    CNPJ: XXXXXXXXXX
    test1: XXXXXXXXXX
    Test1: XXXXXXXXXX
',
1 => '
    IIX - XXXXXXXX
    CNPJ: XXXXXXXXXX
    test2: XXXXXXXXXX
    Test2: XXXXXXXXXX
',
 )
```

I heave this Regex in php code:

```
$regex = '~((?<delimiter>((.*\n{1}CNPJ)+).*?(?=(?&delimiter)|\Z)))~s';
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);
```

separately regex works:

```
(.*\n{1}CNPJ)
```

but when i put into 'delimiter' it does not working

```
'~((?<delimiter>((.*\n{1}CNPJ)+).*?(?=(?&delimiter)|\Z)))~s';
```

Comment: In your text subjects, are there newlines (\n) or is the above just for readability? If so, then I would first explode by the newline (\n) character

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stab (requires the 'g' modifier):

`([IX]* - ((.*) - )?(.*)\nCNPJ: (.*)\ntest[0-9]: (.*)\nTest[0-9]: (.*))+`

Not sure what you expect to match in your "XXXXXX" fields, so I left these as `(.*)`. You can adapt these, of course.

The (.*) correspond to the title and to the content of each field, in that order.

I'm not really a PHP guy, but I hope this helps.

Cheers,
 Paulo

PS: I agree with John--it's probably easier to process this line by line.

**UPDATE**: Fixed the expression to remove an unnecessary 'X'

**UPDATE2**:

If you want to capture the CNPJ (or any other specific field), you can use named capture. For the CNPJ, that would be `([IX]* - ((.*) - )?(.*)\nCNPJ: (?P<cnpj>.*)\ntest[0-9]: (.*)\nTest[0-9]: (.*))+`

Comment: Thank you @PauloMendes and everybody.
To resolve this, first i get All block lines without first line with:
~((?<delimiter>((CNPJ)+).*?(?=(?&delimiter)|\Z)))~s

and after i get only first line:

 "/([IXV]\\s\\D\\s((\\D{1,50})\\nCNPJ))/si"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't using the proper syntax for named groups in PHP's regex engine.  When you want to make a named group you should use (?[regex]). Unfortunately, most regex engines allow for you to reference named groups in the regex using (?p=groupName), but currently php does not support that. Instead, you have to reference the group by number.